# Cross Sections Workshop

Tags: constructions

Next week, a workshop about the cross sections of solids will be held in our school, for 7th grade students. These are what we've decided to include in the workshop:

- Showing ["Flatlad: The Movie"](http://www.flatlandthemovie.com/)
- Giving the students cubic pieces of polystyrene and asking them to make polygon cross sections with given number of sides.

[image]

- Asking the students to construct given solids, using their cross sections by sheets of thin foam board.
- Talking about 3D-Printers and showing clips about them.

**What other things can be included in our workshop? Do you have any suggestions?**

Comment: The regular hexagon cross section of a cube is especially pleasing to see.

Answer (score 3):

[Conic sections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Features) would seem appropriate if you're looking to motivate some of the algebra that is on the horizon for your 7th grade students.

[image: Image from [Tutorvista.com](http://math.tutorvista.com/geometry/cross-section.html)]

Answer (score 1):

Although this has nothing to do with cross sections,
it fits the physical materials:

You could have the students cut out shapes
to illustrate constructive proofs of the Pythagorean theorem:

---

[image]

---

[image]

                     

<sup>(Images from a [Steven Strogatz NYTimes article](http://opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2010/03/14/square-dancing/).)</sup>

---

Another constructive proof is described in [this MESE answer](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/7203/511).